# Makefile - save a command output to a variable? (SHA-256 sum calculation)

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I have modified this snippet to upgrade it to SHA-256 :

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28994/how-can-a-makefile-detect-whether-a-command-is-available-in-the-local-machine

```
determine_sum = \
    sum=; \
    for x in sha256sum sha256 'shasum -a 256' 'openssl dgst -sha256'; do \
        if type "$${x%% *}" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then sum=$$x; break; fi; \
    done; \
    if [ -z "$$sum" ]; then echo 1>&2 "Unable to find a SHA-256 utility"; exit 2; fi

check:
    $(determine_sum); \
    $$sum $(archive_name); \
    #Save ^^^ to a variable - fails
    #archive_sha256=`$$sum $(archive_name)`; \
```

It correctly calculates a SHA-256 checksum - but I am stuck at trying to save the output which I see during the execution of `$$sum $(archive_name); \` to a variable. Please could you help?

Comment: Does CMake relate to the question? If no, delete "cmake" tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
check:
    $(determine_sum); \
    archive_sha256=$$($$sum $(archive_name)); \
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your example really works! Good luck to your projects ;-)